# Is there a way to paginate this array outside of posting it to a database table (Laravel 8)?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I need to paginate an array that is built from client side data. I have built the LengthAwarePaginator with the data coming from a table in the view. Is there a way to continuously pass that variable to the GET method for each page, mimicking the way pagination would work with a database query? I've tried assigning it to $_SESSION['data'] but it doesn't work beyond the first page. I would rather not post the data to a database table.

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

class FooController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      return view('foo');
    }

    public function sheet(Request $request)
    { 
      $c = count($_REQUEST);
      $i = 1;
      
      while ($i <= $c){
        $data[$_REQUEST['v3'.$i][]= array($_REQUEST['v1'.$i], $_REQUEST['v2'.$i]);
        $i += 1;
       }

      $page = isset($request->page) ? $request->page : 1;
      $perPage = 1;
      $offset = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;

      $requestData =  new LengthAwarePaginator(
       array_slice($data, $offset, $perPage, true),
       count($data),
       $perPage,
       $page,
       ['path' => $request->url(), 'query' => $request->query()]
       );

      $_SESSION['data'] = $requestData;

      return view('foo');
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/foo', [FooController::class, 'index'])->name('foo');
Route::post('/foo', [FooController::class, 'sheet']);
```

View

```
@extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
        <div class="flex justify-center">
            <div class="w-12/12 bg-white p-6 rounded-lg">
            {!! $_SESSION['data']->links() !!}
                @foreach($_SESSION['data'] as $key=>$value)
                    <?php echo $key ?>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>          
    @endsection
```

Comment: Laravel doesn't use PHP's sessions

Comment: Is there a way to keep passing the variable through? I think regular paginating doesn't work because it wants to build the paginator each pass through where as in my case the data is only available in the initial POST